# Starting from unique and progressive `ID` to build a new string using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Starting from a MySQL table with the following unique and progressive `IDs`

| ID | pID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 10 |  |
| 100 |  |
| 1000 |  |

I need update the column `pID` of the same MySQL table by constructing a string of type `YYYY-ID`

**Expected Output:**

| ID | pID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-0001 |
| 10 | 2022-0010 |
| 100 | 2022-0100 |
| 1000 | 2022-1000 |

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Are the `ID` values generated automatically as an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column? Or are you providing those values when you insert the row?

Comment: @BillKarwin The `ID` values it's generated automatically and it's `AUTO_INCREMENT` `column

Comment: Okay then the UPDATE shown in @ValeriuCiuca's answer is the best way. It cannot be done in a trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can CONCAT '2022-' string to your ID column, padded with LPAD, filled with 0 on the left:

```
UPDATE table SET pID = CONCAT('2022-', LPAD(ID, 4, 0))
```

If you need current year:

```
UPDATE table SET pID = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y'), '-', LPAD(ID, 4, 0))
```

Comment: What happens with this in 74 days?

Comment: I was updating the  answer when you asked

Comment: If ID = 74 the pID = `0074`